# Admin role to add category in Express API design

Tags: node.js, api, express, admin

Hey I am testing on postman as an admin to add category on my project, I have successfully created admin user and login, but when I tried to add category, postman say: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role') can anyone help?

Here is my user model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  

{
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["user", "admin"],
      default: "user",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

here is my auth middleware:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/user");
const { signupUser, loginUser } = require("../controller/adminauth");

exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.header.authorization) {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[1];
      const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;

      let decodeData;
      if (token && isCustomAuth) {
        decodeData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.UserId = decodeData?.id;
      } else {
        decodeData = jwt.decode(token);
        req.UserId = decodeData?.sub;
      }
      
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // res.status(400).json({ message: "Authorization required" });
  } next ()
};

exports.adminMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.userId.role === "admin") {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Access denied" });
  }
  next();
};
```

Here is my admin auth controller:

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

exports.loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User does not exists." });
    }

    if (!existingUser.role === "admin") {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User is not admin." });
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      existingUser.password
    );

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials." });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        email: existingUser.email,
        id: existingUser._id,
        role: existingUser.role,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "3d" }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ result: existingUser, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

exports.signupUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Admin already exists." });
    if (!password == confirmPassword)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password don't match" });

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const result = await User.create({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      role: "admin",
    });

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { email: result.email, id: result._id, role: result.role },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "3d" }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ result, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Here is my category route:

```
const express = require("express");
const { addCategory, getCategories } = require("../controller/category");
const { auth, adminMiddleware } = require("../middleware/auth");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/category/create", auth, adminMiddleware, addCategory);

router.get("/category/getcategory", getCategories);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your auth middleware,
change your exports.auth with the following code:

```
exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.header.authorization) {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[1];
      const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;

      let decodeData;
      if (token && isCustomAuth) {
        decodeData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.UserId = decodeData||{}; //change this line
      } else {
        decodeData = jwt.decode(token);
        req.UserId = decodeData?.sub;
      }
      
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Authorization required" });
  } next ()
};
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still give me the same error that role is not defined:(

Comment: can you once try logging your decodeData and send me here?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')
    at exports.adminMiddleware (C:\Users\yzhou\Desktop\mern-ecommerce\ecommerce-backend\src\middleware\auth.js:28:19)

Comment: do you think it is this line   if (!req.UserId.role === "admin") problem? but I defined req.UserId above here like you edited, req.UserId = decodeData||{}; //change this line

Comment: ok, I put console.log(decodedata) under the  req.UserId = decodeData||{}; //change this line, and uses postman to try addcategory, still got this: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'role')

Comment: okay, I found the solution. if (!req.UserId.role === "admin") in this condition you are using userId while you are assigning your decoded data to UserId. Change it to either userId or UserId ant both places.

Answer (score 0):

modify the userSchema (remove the following `enum: ["user", "admin"],` )
It worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34493230)